# Adoptable storage filesystem?

Tags: file-system, adoptable-storage, data

I have a sdcard split into two partition: portable and adoptable.
Not long time ago my `/data` is formatted as F2FS, really unstable on my device. So I recently format it again to EXT4. I'm noticing that my adoptable storage is still F2FS even though I already format it again using

```
sm partition disk:***,** mixed 69
```

Is the adoptable filesystem following the device `/data` filesystem or it's default to something?